# How can I benefit from the SE83 SAP Reuse Library?

Tags: abap

I have just come across the SAP reuse library (transaction SE83), but have never used it before.  In the current system there are only a few functions documented, some of which are actually flagged as obsolete by SAP.

Most of these functions/classes are also relatively well-known to anyone that has worked in SAP for any length of time, for example ALV Grids, confirmations prompts, conversion routines etc.

Does SAP release updates/libraries separately to the reuse library?  Does anyone use it on a regular basis, either to find SAP released objects or to document their own internal functions?

SAP Help on the reuse library can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_46c/4.6C/en-US/38/248338c617623ce10000009b38f8cf/content.htm?no_cache=true).

Answer (score 4):

For me the biggest benefit of the reuse library is that it contains source code examples for each of the libraries/functions provided. This is very helpful if you are using something new or haven't used it in a while. In some instances, you have more than one example program that you can use as a base for your own code, or from which you can simply copy the necessary code. The components featured here are supposed to address common requirements which you may have so that you don't have to reinvent things.

To answer your second question:

I don't think that the Reuse library has had any or many updates over the releases. If you click on the "Libraries" button on the toolbar, you will see that the default library shown is "SAP Technology". (Mine contains an extra library called "E-Government Toolbox" which is empty. I think the idea was that it is a "pluggable" way of maintaining a reference of reusable components for developers. The SAP-provided components have not changed over the years, and I am not aware of SAP releasing more reusable components that you can import into your system. Community efforts like [SAPlink](http://code.google.com/p/saplink/) are probably a better bet for sharing reusable components, but then, what is actually needed is a community-driven repository for sharing them.

Like you point out, you could use it to document your own reusable components, but I don't see this as very practical, unless you are developing components that other SAP customers will use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I work at several customer sites, each with their own industry-specific frequently used objects, or "their way" of doing things.  This may still be a reasonable place to document frequently used functions, or new libraries for their in-house support teams.  It just seems like a great tool that's been their for ages, but is clearly underused - even by SAP.  The documented functions only covers a tiny subset of their released/reusable code. Allthough, we all know that when the pressure's on documentations's the first thing out the window, so I shouldn't be too surprised.

Comment: My feeling has always been that developers should use the built-in documentation on ABAP entities (programs, function modules, etc.), but few ever seem to bother. If you combine that with proper naming and modularization, and use of packages, there is never any guessing as to what custom objects are in the system and what they do.